# how to tar in python

Tags: command-line, python, backup, tar

I want to backup my website using a python script.
This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import time
import datetime
from subprocess import call

DATETIME = time.strftime('%Y%d%m-%H%M%S')
BACKUP_PATH = '/Backups/backups/Test/'
WEB_PATH = '/var/www/html'

TAR_CMD = "-zcf " + BACKUP_PATH + DATETIME + "-html.tar.gz " + WEB_PATH
print TAR_CMD
call (["tar",TAR_CMD])
```

The output of TAR_CMD is

> -zcf /Backups/backups/Test/20152111-123016-html.tar.gz /var/www/html

which is correct - calling tar plus this output tars my website - ok.

When running the python script the output is:

> -zcf /Backups/backups/Test/20152111-123150-html.tar.gz /var/www/html
>
> tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
>
> Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `tar ` to `TAR_CMD` and then do `call(TAR_CMD.split())`

Comment: Check my edited answer & if that solved your problem please mark it as accepted..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the command components as elements of a list, so you can add `tar` to the `TAR_CMD` variable and then use `split(' ')` to create a list of command components separated on spaces:

```
TAR_CMD='tar .....'
subprocess.call(TAR_CMD.split(' '))
```

Or directly:

```
subprocess.call('tar ....'.split(' '))
```

Comment: Much better to just write a list. E.g.: `TAR_CMD = ["-zcf ", BACKUP_PATH + DATETIME + "-html.tar.gz", WEB_PATH]`